# LinqToSql - Include linked object in selected result

Tags: linq-to-sql, foreign-keys

I have two tables. Linked with a foreign key.

[image: linked tables]

Now I fetch a row from the field table:

```
IField Field = from f in DataContext.fields
               where f.mapId == mapId && f.x1 == x && f.y1 == y
               select f;
```

Working with this row I need some data from the linked table fieldViews. So I just do somthing like this:

```
[..] Field.FieldViews [..]
```

According to the SQL Profiler Linq To Sql generates the following queries.

```
SELECT
    [t0].[fieldId],
    [t0].[mapId],
    [t0].[x1],
    [t0].[y1]
FROM
    [dbo].[fields] AS [t0]
WHERE 
    ([t0].[mapId] = @p0) AND 
    ([t0].[x1] = @p1) AND 
    ([t0].[y1] = @p2)


SELECT
    [t0].[fieldViewId],
    [t0].[fieldId],
    [t0].[mapUserId]
FROM
    [dbo].[fieldViews] AS [t0]
WHERE
    [t0].[fieldId] = @p0
```

**But I don't want 2 queries.** How can I make LinqToSql to include this linked object within the first query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [DataLoadOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.dataloadoptions.aspx) you can specify that L2S will load the FieldViews records together with the Fields.

Insert something like this before the query:

```
var dlo = new DataLoadOptions();
dlo.LoadWith<Fields>(f => f.FieldViews);
DataContext.LoadOptions = dlo;
```

The server will execute two queries, but within the same call to the server.